# How to create volume-snapshots from an event (resource modification or deletion) or CronJob?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, amazon-eks, k8s-cronjobber

I searched the **[Volume-snapshots](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volume-snapshots/)** documentation for how I can schedule or listen to an event (resource modification or deletion) to provision the snapshot and I didn't find it.

Is it possible to implement this similar schedule using **[Volume-snapshots](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volume-snapshots/)**?

Comment: What happened to the links? Are they supposed to point to k8 documentation?

Comment: I just fixed it, https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volume-snapshots/